How to restore deleted prospect from recycle bin in pardot?
I want to know how we can restore the prospect that is deleted after someone submits a form or does activity in Salesforce
I know the prospect will restore automatically from recycle bin when the prospect submits the Pardot form but in my case, the form is from salesforce and after submission the prospect is not getting restored, so please anyone let me know how to restore the prospect when someone submit the form from salesforce

go through this documentation kindly.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pardot_deleting_prospects.htm&type=5


I know this option but I want to know is possible to use the Pardot automation rule or engagement studio to undelete the prospects if some activity is happened by prospects.
